# Loading Html page from Resource giving UnAuthorizedAccessException in Xamarin Mac

Tags: xamarin.mac

I am developing a application in Xamarin for Mac. I have a html page whose build action is set to `BundledResource`s and it is in root folder. My problem is that when I want to show it in WebView Control, It Does not open it. When I tries to open it using `FileStream` it throws `UnAuthorizedAccessException`. The exception does not comes in debug mode but when I build package through Xamarin and install it on a another machine where Xamarin Studio is not installed it throws the exception. the code is as below.

```
public void LoadHTMLPage()
{
    try
    {
        string filepath= NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource("HTMLPage", "html");
        NSUrl url = new NSUrl(filepath, false);
        string localHtmlUrl = filepath;
        if (File.Exists(localHtmlUrl))
        {
            MsgBox.Show("File Exist","");
            webBrowser.MainFrame.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(url));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Although MsgBox is displayed which shows that html file exists on the path.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have sandboxing turned on (check entitlement file)? That would cause the behavior difference.

Comment: thanx for response, the problem has been solved. it was because the html and other related files has not access. As I gave access the problem was fixed.